# horizontally scroll a table with mouse wheel in react without DOM Selector?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a table horizontally scroll. But it has DOM selector. How I build it with out DOM Selector. Have any way to do it with  state ?

```js
const onWheel = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  const containerScrollPosition = document.getElementById("container").scrollLeft;
  container.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: containerScrollPosition + e.deltaY,
    behaviour: "smooth"
  });
};
```

my demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-lamport-2do0l?file=/src/App.js .

Comment: You would use useRef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `document.getElementById` is a react anti-pattern. Use a react `ref` to access a DOM node.

[refs and the dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Since you have a functional component you can use the `useRef` hook, otherwise, the `createRef` can be used for a class-based component.

[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Moved the `onWheel` handler *into* the component so the ref is in scope. Also removed the optional behavior option, it was misspelled and using the default behavior, which is what you want anyway.

```
function App() {
  const onWheel = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const container = scrollRef.current;
    const containerScrollPosition = scrollRef.current.scrollLeft;

    container.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: containerScrollPosition + e.deltaY,
    });
  };

  const scrollRef = useRef(null);

  const num = 50;
  let points_th = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    points_th.push(<th>Points</th>);
  }

  let row_1 = render_row("Jill", "Smith", 50, num);
  let row_2 = render_row("Eva", "Jackson", 94, num);
  let row_3 = render_row("Adam", "Johnson", 67, num);
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        ref={scrollRef}
        className="container"
        id="container"
        onWheel={onWheel}
      >
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            {points_th}
          </tr>
          {row_1}
          {row_2}
          {row_3}
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit horizontal scroll using ref]

Comment: Your solution does not prevent the vertical scroll. The solution is not good because the page scroll horizontally and vertically at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Scroll behavior requires using DOM manipulation to some extent, however there is an easier way to get a reference to the node you want to scroll. You can create a ref in a hook component using:

`const containerRef = useRef();`

```
<div
    className="container"
    ref={containerRef}
    id="container"
    onWheel={onWheel}
  ></div>
```

And then you can get your container element using:
`const container = containerRef.current;`

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-boyd-m5fg3?file=/src/App.js